# Some html tags are not working in jasper report

Tags: html, mysql, css, tags, jasper-reports

I am working on jasper report. I am fetching data from database in html format.
For example :

```
<html><body><p>A) For <u>active</u> and <b>liquidated</b> <i>commitments</i>, </p>this is sum of <font font-weight=bold>Funded Commitments</font> in USD as of date and Unfunded Commitment in USD as of date,
```

Above part is in my database table

Other than , and fort-weight every html code is working fine.

Does anyone know the reason/solution for this ?

F.Y.I. : I am using MYSQL for database(I don't know if this info is useful).

Comment: your <b> and <i> tag is hidden, try reformatting your post or no one will understand (also foNt weight)

Answer (score 3):

in short, you're missing the fonts required. here's an excellent post explaining what's going on.

"[embedding-fonts-into-pdf-generated-by-jasperreport](http://javaskeleton.blogspot.co.at/2010/12/embedding-fonts-into-pdf-generated-by.html)"

edit: i might be wrong, but i still think it's a font problem. are you sure your FONT_MAP export parameter is setup correctly?

"[html markup doesn't work](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/528625/html-markup-doesnt-work-pdf)"

Comment: Fonts are working fine. I am able to use bold,italic,regular fonts. But this is about HTML tags. I want to use HTML tags to change the font style.

Comment: there are quite a lot of suggested solution in the second link. If those still couldn't help than I got nothing else, I'm only a random jasper user trying to help.